# Sufficient condition for the union of submanifolds to be a submanifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I have two submanifolds $M^n,N^n\subset W^m$. What are some sufficient condition for their union to be a submanifold too? (by submanifold I always mean smooth)

My guess is that if $M \cap N$ is an n-submanifold which is open and $\overline{M}\cap \overline{N}=\overline{M \cap N}$, then $M\cup N$ is a submanifold. Does anyone have a reference for a statement similar to this one? Or a proof of this? My idea to prove this would be to find for each point on $M \cup N$ a neighborhood completely contained in either $M$ or $N$.

According to the accepted answer in this mathoverflow question which is very similar to mine (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78733/when-is-the-union-of-embedded-smooth-manifolds-a-smooth-manifold), a sufficient condition would be that $M\cap N$ is a n-submanifold and $\overline{M}\cap N=\overline{M\cap N}\cap N$.
I think this is wrong: Consider $M=[-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $N \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to be the graph of the smooth function $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R},t\mapsto \begin{cases} 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ if \ \ t \in [-1,0] \\ e^{-t^{-2}} \ \ \ if  \ \ t>0\end{cases}$. Then the previous conditions hold, but obviously $M \cup N$ does not define a submanifold (removing the point (0,1) produces 3 components). But I am looking for a similar condition.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are these closed submanifolds? My vote is that they be disjoint.

Comment: In your example $M, N$ are not submanifolds.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin They are smooth submanifolds, possibly with boundary.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan they are submanifolds with boundary right?

Comment: If you allow boundaries (which you should have said explicitly to start with), then you can glue along the boundaries, provided the gluing can be done smoothly.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Do you have a reference where on how to glue submanifolds together  along their boundary to obtain a new submanifold? Or any result about this? I only know statements regarding gluing of manifolds, not submanifolds inside an ambient space. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of my answer, all manifolds are assumed to have empty boundary.

Consider the following curves in the Cartesian plane:

$C$ is the unit circle centered at $(0,1)$, $J$ is the interval in the $x$-axis given by the inequalities $-1<x\le 0$. I let
$C_+$ denote the open semicircle in $C$ given by the inequality $0<x$.

I will define two smooth curves:
$$
M= J\cup C_+, N= C \setminus \{(0,0)\}. 
$$

**Remark.** Note that $M$ is only $C^1$-smooth, but one can easily modify the example to achieve $C^\infty$-smoothness.

Clearly, both $M, N$ are diffeomorphic to the real line, hence, are 1-dimensional submanifolds in the plane. Their intersection is $C_+$, clearly also a 1-dimensional smooth submanifold in the plane. At the same time, $M\cup N$ is not a even a topological manifold (it is not locally Euclidean at the point $(0,0)$).

Now, let's check your condition:
$$
\bar{M}\cap \bar{N}=\overline{M\cap N}.
$$
Both sides are equal to $\overline{C_+}$, hence, your condition is satisfied. Thus, your conjecture is incorrect.

Let us test the same example agains the linked MO answer.  There, there were two requirements (not one):

(a) $\bar{M}\cap N= \overline{M\cap N} \cap N$,

(b) $\bar{N}\cap M= \overline{N\cap M} \cap M$.

It is straightforward to see that both are satisfied: The intersection in (a) equals the half-closed arc
$\overline{C_+}\setminus  \{(0,0)\}$ and the intersection in (b) equals the half-closed arc $C_+ \cup  \{(0,0)\}$. Hence, the linked answer is also wrong.

---

**Edit.** Here is a sufficient condition for $M\cup N$ to be a smooth submanifold, provided that $M$, $N$ are $n$-dimensional submanifolds in $W$ and $M\cap N$ is also an $n$-dimensional submanifold.

Assume that the pair $(M,N)$ satisfies the following property:

(a) For every sequence $(x_i)$ in $N$ converging to a point $x\in M$, for all sufficiently large $i$, $x_i\in M$.

(b) Same as (a) with the roles of $M, N$ swapped.

It is easy to see that under this condition, both inclusion maps $M\to M\cup N$, $N\to M\cup N$ are open. From this it is immediate that $M\cup N$ is a smooth submanifold of $W$. (The domain $U$ of an smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ in $M$ or $N$ is open in $M\cup N$, hence, $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth chart in $M\cup N$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for this counterexample. Would you have an idea on an extra condition I could impose so this cannot happen, and that would guarantee $M\cup N$ to be a submanifold? I also think that M is not smooth at (0,0) yet, but can easily be made smooth right?

Comment: @LéoMousseau: $M$ is smooth everywhere; $M\cup N$ is not a topological manifold (at $(0,0)$ it is locally a tripod). How can it be easily made smooth I do not understand. No, I do not have an idea of an extra condition at this point.

Comment: No, I agree that $M\cup N$ cannot be made smooth. I meant one can make $M$ smooth. But maybe you are right that $M$ is already smooth.

Comment: @LéoMousseau: I see what you mean: $M$ is only $C^1$-smooth. One can indeed easily modify this example to make $M$ a $C^\infty$-submanifold by replacing $C_+$ with a suitable curve.

Comment: @LéoMousseau: See also the edit with a sufficient condition for the union to be a submanifold. I do not particularly like it, but it is the best I can think of.

Comment: I think it's a good condition, since in practice it is not harder than to show than some equality involving the closure. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Allowing the submanifolds to intersect in another submanifold allows too much. For example consider two lines intersecting once in the plane. The intersection point is just a 0-dimensional manifold. But its union is a cross smd so not a manifold.

I expect if the closure of a finite number of submanifolds has disjoint intersection then its union is a submanifold.

Comment: Presumably, the condition the OP has in mind is that the intersection is a manifold of the same dimension...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: That would work.

Comment: Indeed, the intersection also is a submanifold of same dimension.

Comment: @Leo Mosseau: No, it's not necessarily the case that the intersection is of the same dimension. It is neccessarily of the same dimension or lower.

Comment: To the downvoter, given the question asks for a "sufficient" condition, can you explain why my answer doesn't provide a sufficient condition???

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah I mean that indeed, the intersection must be of the same dimension as the two submanifolds, BY ASSUMPTION. This is why I wrote that $M\cap N$ should be a n-submanifold, not just a submanifold of any dimension.

Comment: @MoziburUllah It is a sufficient condition, but it's too trivial. I want one in the case where the intersection of the two submanifolds is non-empty.