# Union of two manifolds of different dimension is still a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I know the union of two manifolds, let’s say of dimension k both, is a manifold iff in every point p of the intersection, you can find an open neighborhood in the union such that it looks like (an open subset of) R^{k}.
But, how would this work for two manifolds M and N of dimensions m and n respectively?
M and N are not disjoint necessarily.

Comment: Can you state your definition of manifold? Right now it seems that you are considering submanifolds of Euclidean spaces.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273320/can-a-topological-manifold-be-non-connected-and-each-component-with-different-di/2273365#2273365 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637062/sufficient-condition-for-the-union-of-submanifolds-to-be-a-submanifold/4642619#4642619